# ¿Cómo obtener el máximo z-index de los elementos de una pagina?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Estoy armando una pequeña librería de notificaciones flotantes en la pagina y me surgió la duda al problema, dado que en la pagina donde la usare existen diversos elementos flotantes como modales y botones provenientes de plugins de terceros.

Una primera solución seria usar un valor alto para `z-index` digamos:

```
.floating-notification {
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Pero el problema es que al ser un número fijo no me asegura que sea el mas grande ya que alguien en alguna libreria de terceros puede haber pensado un número mayor supongamos **10001** por lo que si ambos componentes se muestran juntos el que cree se mostrara debajo.

Otra solución forzada seria utilizar el maximo valor admisible para `z-index` pero este varia segun el navegador y no es estandar.

La duda es si existe alguna manera de saber de todos los elementos del DOM cual es el valor maximo del atributo z-index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La siguiente afirmación:

> Pero el problema es que al ser un número fijo no me asegura que sea el
>   mas grande ya que alguien en alguna libreria de terceros puede haber
>   pensado un número mayor supongamos 10001 por lo que si ambos
>   componentes se muestran juntos el que cree se mostrara debajo.

Y la siguiente duda:

> La duda es si existe alguna manera de saber de todos los elementos del
>   DOM cual es el valor maximo del atributo z-index.

No son del todo compatibles. No es necesario encontrar el máximo `z-index` de todo el documento, ya que `z-index` define un [contexto de apilamiento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/entendiendo_z_index/El_contexto_de_apilamiento) (del ingles *stacking context*)

Dos elementos pertenecientes a distintos contextos de apilamiento no se pueden comparar mediante sus `z-index`

Considera el siguiente ejemplo, sacado de la red de MDN:

[image: z-index y el contexto de apilamiento]

En el, se puede apreciar que a pesar de que el `DIV #4` tiene un `z-index: 6`, no se dibuja sobre el `DIV #1` con `z-index: 5`

Luego, solo te interesan los nodos hijos directos a partir del nodo sobre el que quieres dibujar tu contenido.

Un codigo que te serviría para ello, es el siguiente:

```
function maximoZindex(from){
  var max = 0;
  from.find(">*").each(function(i, e){
    var z = Number($(e).css("z-index"));
    if(z > max) {
      max = z;
    }
  });
  return max;
}

console.log("maximo z-index a partir de body", maximoZindex($("body")));
```

Puedes probarlo en el siguiente snippet:

```js
function maximoZindex(from){
  var max = 0;
  from.find(">*").each(function(i, e){
    var z = Number($(e).css("z-index"));
    if(z > max) {
      max = z;
    }
  });
  return max;
}

console.log("maximo z-index a partir de body", maximoZindex($("body")));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  padding: 20px;
  font: 12px/20px Arial, sans-serif;
}
div {
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: relative;
}
h1 {
  font: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#div1,
#div2 {
  border: 1px dashed #696;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #cfc;
}
#div1 {
  z-index: 5;
  margin-bottom: 190px;
}
#div2 {
  z-index: 2;
}
#div3 {
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 180px;
  width: 330px;
  border: 1px dashed #900;
  background-color: #fdd;
  padding: 40px 20px 20px;
}
#div4,
#div5 {
  border: 1px dashed #996;
  background-color: #ffc;
}
#div4 {
  z-index: 6;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 25px 10px 5px;
}
#div5 {
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
#div6 {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 180px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 125px;
  border: 1px dashed #009;
  padding-top: 125px;
  background-color: #ddf;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context -->

<div id="div1">
  <h1>Division Element #1</h1>
  <code>position: relative;<br/>
  z-index: 5;</code>
</div>

<div id="div2">
  <h1>Division Element #2</h1>
  <code>position: relative;<br/>
  z-index: 2;</code>
</div>

<div id="div3">
  <div id="div4">
    <h1>Division Element #4</h1>
    <code>position: relative;<br/>
    z-index: 6;</code>
  </div>

  <h1>Division Element #3</h1>
  <code>position: absolute;<br/>
  z-index: 4;</code>

  <div id="div5">
    <h1>Division Element #5</h1>
    <code>position: relative;<br/>
    z-index: 1;</code>
  </div>
   
  <div id="div6">
    <h1>Division Element #6</h1>
    <code>position: absolute;<br/>
    z-index: 3;</code>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, desconocía que el z-index dependía del componente padre, pero esto es solo si el atributo `position: relative` en caso de `position: absolute` ¿funciona igual?.

Comment: @Ricardo funciona igual, te recomiendo leer el articulo de [contexto de apilamiento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/entendiendo_z_index/El_contexto_de_apilamiento) que enlace de la red de MDN, en el explican mucho mejor cuando se crean, son varios los casos.

Answer (score 3):

No hay un método elegante de hacerlo, tendrás que mirar todos los elementos y quedarte con el z-index más alto:

```js
let all= Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('body *'));
console.log('Encontrados ',all.length,' elementos');
let allIndexes=all.map((elem)=>{
  if (elem.style) {
    return +elem.style.zIndex || 0;
  }
  return -9999;
});
console.log('Valores encontrados:', allIndexes.toString());
let max=Math.max.apply(null,allIndexes);
console.log('Max z-index:',max);
```

```css
.cl {
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="cl" style="z-index: 3;width:100px;height:100px;background:#A00;"></div>
<div class="cl" style="z-index: 4;width:90px;height:90px;background:#0A0;"></div>
<div class="cl" style="z-index: 5;width:50px;height:50px;background:#AA0;"></div>
<div class="cl" style="z-index: 6;width:40px;height:40px;background:#AAA"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No existe un función nativa o algo parecido, hay que hacerlo a mano. Te dejo el ejemplo en Jquery, por que ya tienes uno en Javascript, con el que te acomode más.

```js
$(function(){
 var all = $("*");
  var max = all.length, index = 0;

 for (var i=0; i < max; i++) {
    var temp = $(all[i]).css('z-index');
    if( temp != 'auto' && parseInt( index ) < parseInt( temp ) ){
     index = temp;
    }
    
 }
  
  alert('El z-index más alto es: ' + index);
  
})
```

```css
div{ 
position: relative;
min-width: 50%;
min-height: 50px;
margin: 5%;
padding: 10%;
background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.zindex1{ z-index: 15;}
.zindex2{ z-index: 2;}
.zindex3{ z-index: 30;}
.zindex4{ z-index: 60;}
.zindex5{ z-index: 100;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="zindex1"></div>
<div class="zindex2"></div>
<div class="zindex3"></div>
<div class="zindex4"></div>
<div class="zindex5"></div>
```